# c# Using custom filter attribute on a generic controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics

I have created myself a new **AuthorizeClaim** filter and attribute which works on my API. It looks like this:

```
public class AuthorizeClaimFilter: IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly string[] _claims;
    public AuthorizeClaimFilter(string[] claims) => _claims = claims;

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (_claims.Any())
        {
            var user = context.HttpContext.User;
            if (user.IsInRole(SituIdentityConstants.Roles.Administrator)) return;

            var hasClaim = user.Claims.Any(c =>
                c.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Role &&
                _claims.Any(x => x.Equals(c.Value)));

            if (hasClaim) return;
        }

        context.Result = new ForbidResult();
    }
}

public class AuthorizeClaimAttribute: TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public AuthorizeClaimAttribute(params string[] values) : base(typeof(AuthorizeClaimFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] {values};
    }
}
```

This works fine in our API, but in my infinite wisdom, a while ago (about a year ago) I created some generic controllers:

```
[ApiController]
public class GenericController<T> : GenericController<T, int> where T : BaseModel, IKey<int>
{
    public GenericController(IMediator mediator) : base(mediator)
    {
    }
}

[ApiController]
public class GenericController<T, TKey> : ControllerBase where T: BaseModel, IKey<TKey>
{
    public readonly IMediator Mediator;
    public GenericController(IMediator mediator)
    {
        Mediator = mediator;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an entity by id
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The id of the entity</param>
    /// <returns>The entity</returns>
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    [ApiConventionMethod(typeof(AttemptApiConventions), nameof(AttemptApiConventions.AttemptGet))]
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult<T>> GetAsync(TKey id) =>
        Ok(await Mediator.Send(new GenericGet<T, TKey>(id)));

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model">The entity to create</param>
    /// <returns>The created entity</returns>
    [HttpPost]
    [ApiConventionMethod(typeof(AttemptApiConventions), nameof(AttemptApiConventions.AttemptPost))]
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult<T>> CreateAsync(T model) =>
        Ok(await Mediator.Send(new GenericCreate<T, TKey>(model, User)))
            .WithMessage<T>(string.Format(Resources.EntityCreated, typeof(T).Name));

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates a new entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model">The entity to update</param>
    /// <returns>The created entity</returns>
    [HttpPut]
    [ApiConventionMethod(typeof(AttemptApiConventions), nameof(AttemptApiConventions.AttemptPost))]
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult<T>> UpdateAsync(T model) =>
        Ok(await Mediator.Send(new GenericUpdate<T, TKey>(model, User)))
            .WithMessage<T>(string.Format(Resources.EntityUpdated, typeof(T).Name));

    /// <summary>
    /// Deletes an entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The id of the entity</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    [ApiConventionMethod(typeof(AttemptApiConventions), nameof(AttemptApiConventions.AttemptPost))]
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult<bool>> DeleteAsync(TKey id) =>
        Ok(await Mediator.Send(new GenericDelete<T, TKey>(id)))
            .WithMessage<bool>(string.Format(Resources.EntityDeleted, typeof(T).Name));
}
```

These have been working absolutely fine and satisfied our needs, but now I have come to use different claims to access different endpoints (hence the new attribute filter). I now need to somehow pass the claims to the generic controllers.
I tried to do something like this:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[AuthorizeClaim($"{typeof(T)}:read")]
[ApiConventionMethod(typeof(AttemptApiConventions), nameof(AttemptApiConventions.AttemptGet))]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult<T>> GetAsync(TKey id) =>
    Ok(await Mediator.Send(new GenericGet<T, TKey>(id)));
```

But I get an error stating:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

which makes sense, so I tried to think of another solution.
I came up with the idea of registering a class that holds a list of my claims:

```
public class RequiredClaimHandler : IRequiredClaimHandler
{
    public readonly List<RequiredClaim> Claims;
    public RequiredClaimHandler(List<RequiredClaim> claims) => Claims = claims;

    public string[] Get(HttpMethod action, Type type)
    {
        var claim = Claims?.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Action == action && m.Type == type);

        return claim != null && claim.UseDefault ? GetDefault(claim) : claim?.Claims;
    }

    private static string[] GetDefault(RequiredClaim claim)
    {
        var action = claim.Action == HttpMethod.Get ? "read" : "write";

        return new[] {$"{claim.Type.Name.ToLower()}:{action}"};
    }
}
```

The idea was to then register it as a singleton and create a factory method like this:

```
public static class RequiredClaimHandlerFactory
{
    public static IRequiredClaimHandler Create(List<RequiredClaim> claims) =>
        new RequiredClaimHandler(claims);
}
```

I wrote the unit tests and then created a new attribute filter:

```
public class AuthorizeRequiredClaimFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IRequiredClaimHandler _handler;
    private readonly Type _type;
    private readonly HttpMethod _method;
    public AuthorizeRequiredClaimFilter(IRequiredClaimHandler handler, Type type, HttpMethod method)
    {
        _handler = handler;
        _type = type;
        _method = method;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (_handler.Get(_method, _type) != null) return;

        context.Result = new ForbidResult();
    }
}

public class AuthorizeRequiredClaimAttribute: TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public AuthorizeRequiredClaimAttribute(HttpMethod method, Type type) : base(typeof(AuthorizeRequiredClaimFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] {method, type};
    }
}
```

Then I updated my generic method:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[AuthorizeRequiredClaim(HttpMethod.Get, typeof(T))]
[ApiConventionMethod(typeof(AttemptApiConventions), nameof(AttemptApiConventions.AttemptGet))]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult<T>> GetAsync(TKey id) =>
    Ok(await Mediator.Send(new GenericGet<T, TKey>(id)));
```

But of course, I am back where I started....
These parameters are not constants.

Does anyone know how I can get around this? I would prefer **not** to abandon my generic controllers as they are useful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand this point `I now need to somehow pass the claims to the generic controllers` - I don't see any direct involvement between claims and controllers, we have `HttpContext` as the flow to connect everything. Also what you're trying to do as I see is to pass the generic type argument `T` (of the generic controller) to the attribute, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer**

You can inject [IActionContextAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.iactioncontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-6.0) in `AuthorizeClaimFilter` in order to get generic type from controller (or action parameter etc.) and use it as a prefix while checking claims. Don't forget to register `IActionContextAccessor` in `Startup`

```
services.TryAddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

**AuthorizeClaimFilter**

```
public class AuthorizeClaimFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly string[] _claims;
    private readonly bool _useGenericPrefix;
    private readonly IActionContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    private const string PrefixSeparator = ":";

    public AuthorizeClaimFilter(string[] claims, bool useGenericPrefix, IActionContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _claims = claims;
        _useGenericPrefix = useGenericPrefix;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (_claims.Any())
        {
            //calculate values only if needed
            var descriptor = (ControllerActionDescriptor)_httpContextAccessor.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor;
            //add more complex for selecting generic parameter
            //and it depends on your controller hierarchy
            var type = descriptor.ControllerTypeInfo.BaseType.GenericTypeArguments.First();

            var claims = _useGenericPrefix
                ? _claims.Select(a => $"{type.Name}{PrefixSeparator}{a}").ToArray()
                : _claims;

            var user = context.HttpContext.User;
            if (user.IsInRole(SituIdentityConstants.Roles.Administrator)) return;

            var hasClaim = user.Claims.Any(c =>
                c.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Role &&
                claims.Any(x => x.Equals(c.Value)));

            if (hasClaim) return;
        }

        context.Result = new ForbidResult();
    }
}
```

**AuthorizeClaimAttribute**

```
public class AuthorizeClaimAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    private string[] _claims;

    private bool _useGenericPrefix;
    public bool UseGenericPrefix
    {
        get => _useGenericPrefix;
        set
        {
            if (_useGenericPrefix != value)
            {
                Arguments = new object[] { _claims, value };
            }

            _useGenericPrefix = value;
        }
    }

    public AuthorizeClaimAttribute(params string[] values) : base(typeof(AuthorizeClaimFilter))
    {
        _claims = values;
        Arguments = new object[] { _claims, false };
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
[HttpGet("claim")]
[AuthorizeClaim("read", UseGenericPrefix = true)]
public IActionResult TestClaim()
```

**Old answer. Doesn't compile now, but may be working in future versions of C# with introduction of generic attributes**

You can stick to first option using `AuthorizeClaimFilter`/`AuthorizeClaimAttribute` with updated `AuthorizeClaimAttribute`

```
public class AuthorizeClaimAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    private string[] _claims;

    public string PrefixSeparator { get; set; } = ":";

    private object _prefix;
    public object Prefix
    {
        get => _prefix;
        set
        {
            _prefix = value;
            _claims = _claims.Select(a => $"{_prefix}{PrefixSeparator}{a}").ToArray();
            Arguments = new object[] { _claims }; ;
        }
    }

    public AuthorizeClaimAttribute(params string[] values) : base(typeof(AuthorizeClaimFilter))
    {
        _claims = values;
        Arguments = new object[] { _claims };
    }
}
```

And usage is

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[AuthorizeClaim("read", Prefix = typeof(T)]
[ApiConventionMethod(typeof(AttemptApiConventions), nameof(AttemptApiConventions.AttemptGet))]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult<T>> GetAsync(TKey id) =>
    Ok(await Mediator.Send(new GenericGet<T, TKey>(id)));
```

In this case case you will get claims prefixed with `T` fully qualified name. If you need only short name of the type you can modify `AuthorizeClaimAttribute` to accept `Type` prefix and prepend `_prefix.Name` to claims, or implement more sophisticated logic for this

```
public class AuthorizeClaimAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    private string[] _claims;

    public string PrefixSeparator { get; set; } = ":";

    private Type _prefix;
    public Type Prefix
    {
        get => _prefix;
        set
        {
            _prefix = value;
            _claims = _claims.Select(a => $"{_prefix.Name}{PrefixSeparator}{a}").ToArray();
            Arguments = new object[] { _claims }; ;
        }
    }

    public AuthorizeClaimAttribute(params string[] values) : base(typeof(AuthorizeClaimFilter))
    {
        _claims = values;
        Arguments = new object[] { _claims };
    }
}
```

Comment: this will not compile

Comment: @NourAlhuda What's the error and where is it?

Comment: check this   [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/generic-attributes)  @Alexander

Comment: @NourAlhuda Where are generic attributes in my code?

Comment: the doc talks about type parameters still being disallowed even for generic attributes @Alexander

Comment: @NourAlhuda Good point, thanks. Will review my answer

Comment: @NourAlhuda Updated my answer. Please check if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

been trying to work around this for hours.
but there seem no way but implementing an `AuthorizationHandler` and use
`AuthorizationService`

```
 [HttpGet("{id}")]
[ApiConventionMethod(typeof(AttemptApiConventions), nameof(AttemptApiConventions.AttemptGet))]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult<T>> GetAsync(TKey id,[FromServices]IAuthorizationService _authorizationService)
```